# Unable to install Anaconda

Tags: web-scraping, anaconda, failed-installation

I am trying to install Anaconda (Anaconda2-5.0.1-Windows-x86_64) but I could not install it. I am using windows 10 64 bits. As I tried to install I got error saying "Error opening file for writing". Please see uploaded image for reference
[image: Error].

Comment: You probably have something running in the background that is prohibiting the installation from writing to disk.  And why install Anaconda2?   Restart the computer. Try Anaconda3.

Comment: @pylang:  thanks for your comment.  As I tried to download anaconda3 I could not download, downloading interrupted in the middle of downloading.

Answer (score 0):

When I downloaded and Installed Anaconda3 
My ***FIREWALL or ANTI-VIRUS*** is turn off
If you have any, try to disabled it then reboot/restart your computer 
and then try again. Here some link for downloading [anaconda3](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) and some [repo](https://github.com/Romeliigalbia/Face-Detection-with-Datasets-and-Training-for-Face-Recognition-Using-OpenCV3-Python3/blob/master/Follow%20This%20Steps%20Carefully) steps for installing properly the anaconda3, chillax and find another suitable answer for your question.

Comment: @sunjeep maybe because I did not encounter your problem, that's why.
Try another approach of question by not focusing the anaconda install but the install itself. Hope you get it.

Comment: @sunjeep always in helping hand